# Make a subclass out of a existing superclass field

Tags: java, superclass

I need to create a sub-class of a existing class, which I know how to do, but I need to be able to create the subclass based off a existing super class without modifying the super class.

For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }
    private int _a;
}
public class Bar extends Foo
{
    public Bar(int a, int b)
    {
        super(a);
        _b = b;
    }
    public Bar(Foo foo, int b)
    {
        ???? //<----What do I do here?
        _b = b;
    }
    private int _b;
}
public static class Baz
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo(1);
        Bar bar = new Bar(foo, 2); //<---- How do I set this up?
    }
}
```

So in the above example it would use the existing instance of Foo and turn it in to a Bar and set the _b field to 2.

**EDIT**

Important constraint, I did not think everyone would tell me to edit Foo. I can not change Foo, that class is in a library I can not edit, so what I want to do needs to be done without editing Foo.

**EDIT2**

Here is the actual Foo, it is the ChunkProvider class from Minecraft.

```
public class ChunkProvider
    implements IChunkProvider
{

    public ChunkProvider(World world, IChunkLoader ichunkloader, IChunkProvider ichunkprovider)
    {
        chunkSet = new HashSet();
        chunkMap = new HashMap();
        chunkList = new ArrayList();
        field_28064_b = new EmptyChunk(world, new byte[32768], 0, 0);
        field_28066_g = world;
        field_28069_d = ichunkloader;
        field_28070_c = ichunkprovider;
    }

    //(Snip) There are no GetXXX members for the below fields.

   private Set chunkSet;
    private Chunk field_28064_b;
    private IChunkProvider field_28070_c;
    private IChunkLoader field_28069_d;
    private Map chunkMap;
    private List chunkList;
    private World field_28066_g;

}
```

Comment: What are the visibility modifiers of the fields?

Comment: What about creating a wrapper for ChunkProvider and extend this wrapper?

Comment: @Stefan The problem is this class gets generated by World and saved (which I can replace). My final goal is to have World call my version instead of it's version.

Comment: Any chance to manipulate World? For instance, use a subclass or something?

Comment: @Stefan its just turtles all the way down. But @Jordão posted a solution that fits my needs perfectly.

Comment: Does your snip comment mean that you did not include the getters?

Comment: @MirroredFate There are no getters for the fields, they are all used internally within the class, but none are exposed to the outside.

Comment: Minecraft is so terribly designed (in terms of modding).  I really wish that Notch would encapsulate things a bit better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way around this, and it is not to inherit `Foo`, but to compose it and delegate to its methods.

I noticed that the "real" `Foo` implements an interface. If you could design your code around that interface and not around the concrete `Foo`, `Bar` can be like this:

```
public class Bar implements IFoo {
  public Bar(IFoo foo, ...) {
    _foo = foo;
  }
  private IFoo _foo;
  // implement IFoo delegating all calls to _foo...
}
```

Comment: I'm in a similar situation where unfortunately the Foo class does not implement an interface. I wish it did, because that would make my life easier in uncountable other ways as well, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

If Foo's private variable _a does not have an accessor method and you can't change Foo then there is no way, short of some [reflection](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=321191), to do what you describe. You simple do not have access to Foo._a.

Comment: Sigh, I think that is what I will have to do. I will leave the question open for a day or two in case some kind of magic answer comes that is not reflection.

Comment: [or not...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473790/make-a-subclass-out-of-a-existing-superclass-field/6474034#6474034)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through `Foo.class.getDeclaredFields()`, looking for one with the name `_a`. Call `Field.setAccessible(true)` on the field, then `Field.getValue()` will give you the value you need.

I keep this more general code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T getFieldValue(Object target, String name) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<? extends Object> c = target.getClass();
    Field field = findField(c, name);
    if (field == null)
        throw new NoSuchFieldException(name);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return (T) field.get(target);
}

public static Field findField(Class<? extends Object> clas, String name) {
    if (clas == null)
        return null;
    Field[] declaredFields = clas.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        if (field.getName().equals(name))
            return field;
    }
    return findField(clas.getSuperclass(), name);
}
```

lying around for just such eventualities.

Comment: Assuming the OP really knows that Foo looks like that... `_a` may not exist at all as a field.

Comment: In which case he can list the fields and take a punt - but he does seem to have the source.

Answer (score 0):

just call

`super(foo.getA()) // assuming you have a getA method`

where your question marks are.

you cannot make the new Bar instance be foo. (If you can, I will definitely have learned something today).

Comment: Please see my update. Foo is in a library that I can not change. Is there any other way round this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Foo` constructor that takes a `Foo` as an argument and makes a copy of `_a`, then invoke that constructor where you have indicated.

EDIT:

```
public class Bar extends Foo
{
    public Bar(int a, int b)
    {
        super(a);
        _b = b;
    }
    public Bar(Foo foo, int b)
    {
        super(foo.getA(),b);  <------
        _b = b;
    }
    private int _b;
}
```

Comment: Please see my update. Foo is in a library that I can not change. Is there any other way round this?

Comment: If you cannot change `Foo`, and if Foo does not have a `getA()` method, then you're out of luck.  The value of `_a` is inaccessible.  If `Foo` has a method `getA()` then use that to call `super(foo.getA())`.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of super(foo.getA()) in use? I am having a little trouble understanding.

Comment: @scott, just replace your line with question marks with the line in my answer.  Note that @jim answer is another approach; its called a copy constructor.

Comment: This is using @hvgotcode's solution.  Usable only if `Foo` has a method that will return the value of `_a`.

Comment: Foo does not have any methods that return _a.

Comment: You mention that `Foo` is in a 3rd-party library. Is it publicly available and if so, what is the real class name (and library)?

Comment: @Jim Garrison I updated the main post, and it's not really a library, it is the main jar for Minecraft and I am writing a mod for it. I would rather do reflection over changing the jar as I would break any other mods that use ChunkProvider.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source to Foo, copy it adding the methods you need to access its fields etc, and then place your copy in the classpath ahead of the original.

Comment: This is a mod for minecraft, I would rather do reflection over doing that as it would break any other mods that did need to change the class. My mod does not even run in game (it is a external map generator that calls in to the game engine to make the map). I think the inconvenience factor is too high.

Comment: Even nasty hacks have their own engineering tradeoffs!